# Lookup relationship filter by related object's junction relationship

Tags: community, lookup, lookup-filter

I have the ff:

Product object with multi select picklist State.
Payment object with string State.

`Payment` will have a lookup relationship to `Product` but I need to filter products so that it will only show those that are in the same state as payment's state.

I found out that lookup filter doesn't allow multi select. (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_limitations.htm&type=5)

I updated Product's state to an object and a junction relationship was created between Products and State. (Products per state)

I was hoping I could add something like this in the Payment to Product look up filter:
Payment > State EQUALS to Product > Products Per State > State > Name but that's not possible as well.

I thought of creating a field in Products called `All_States` and use a trigger so that every time Products_Per_State was created/updated/deleted it will update the related Product's All_State field. (I haven't done triggers but I am  hoping that is possible. I couldnt use formula for All_States because that isn't allowed in lookup filter as well.)

With that I can do this in lookup filter:
Product > All_States contains Payment > State

---

I'm not a 100% confident with this solution. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your information of MD objects is not relevant

Anyways you can use [LookUp filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&type=5) for your use case.

While setting up the lookup filter you will get option to select current record or lookup and the field comparison between `value/field`.

[image]

Comment: I was trying this. Lookup Payment to Product with filter:  Payment: City equal to field ____ but only Product object is shown. I need to be able to access Product's Cities name

Comment: There will be two options there, source field and lookup field, you need to select from there.